# Python - Requests - BeatuifulSoup - HTML found when running script locally but not found when running on VPS

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am having a weird issue when I try to run a basic test script which should output the event name from the HTML of a URL using Beautifulsoup.#

The code is below:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def makesoup(url):
    cookies = {'mycountries' : '101,28,3,102,42,10,18,4,2,22', 'user_time_zone': 'Europe/London',  'user_time_zone_id': '1'} 
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.post(url,  headers=headers,  cookies=cookies)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
   
def linkscrape(links, savefile):
    baseurl = "https://sport-tv-guide.live"
    urllist = []
    
    for link in links:
        finalurl = (baseurl+ link['href'])
        urllist.append(finalurl)
        print(finalurl)
        
    for singleurl in urllist:
        soup2=makesoup(url=singleurl)
        g_data=soup2.find_all('div', {'id': 'channelInfo'})
    
        
        for match in g_data:
            print(g_data)
            try:
                event =  match.find('div', class_='title full').text.strip()
                print(event)
            except:
                event = ""


            
def matches():
    
    dict = {"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/boxing":"/var/scripts/output/boxing.txt"}
    
    for key,  value in dict.items():
        soup=makesoup(url=key)
        game_check = soup.find('div',  class_='alert alert-info')
        if game_check is not None:
            with open(value ,"w") as text_file:
                text_file.writelines("No games found for event")
        else:
            linkscrape(links=soup.find_all('a',  {'class': 'article flag',  'href': True}),  savefile = value)

matches()
```

When I run the code locally I receive the following output:

[image: expected]

When I run the exact same code on my VPS server, I receive the following output:

[image: unexpected]

I was thinking at first the website was blocking the request based on user agent, so I added the headers in the code above but issue persisted. The only other thing I can think of is that the site is blocking the IP of the VPS server, although strangely enough it is printing out the correct URL, but the HTML of the URL is not being outputted/found by Beautifulsoup when I am using a VPS.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions anyone has to possibly resolve this issue.

Comment: Does your VPS have any outgoing firewall rules? (VPS is virtual private server?)

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly hitting the domain's captcha service or other filter due to using a commercial IP. Request the page you are trying to scrape, save it to a file, and examine what the webserver is sending you. you can also use `r.status_code` as part of your troubleshooting.